# Positioning floating element using JavaScript (for animation)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to make floating `HTML5` element move back and forward on my page. Exactly like `SmoothDivScrolling` that is already out there. I did try `SmoothDivScrolling` and it is not working well with the layout of my page.

So I have started to write my own.

If I give a position to my element using `CSS` I will be able to retrieve the position with:

```
element = document.getElementById(image);
position = element.style.left;
// removing px from the value
position = parseInt(position.substring(0,position.length-2));
```

This will return the left position of the element inside its parent only if the `CSS` contain:

```
left:0px;
```

As mentioned, I want my elements to be floating because I plan to have many more than one element;

Now since I want to animate my element I have to change the position by changing the value of `0px` with:

```
fish.style.left = (newPosition)+'px';
```

It is working if I provide the style of my floating element with:

```
position:relative;   //This doesnt really afect my floating
left:0px;            //this does
```

So I tried to retrieve the position with `DOM` instead of `CSS` using:

```
var element = document.getElementById(image);
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
position   = rect.left;
```

Now this is working. It retrieves the position of the element relative to the body even if no left positioning was specified in the style.

I am wondering if there is way to change the position of that element without going trough `CSS` style. Because each element might have different width, floating them take care of the positioning. If I provide a position to each of them they won't be floating anymore.

The floating option avoid all the math involved on positioning. But if it's really needed I guess I will do the math.

Any suggestions?

Here is the full code for who ever wants to reinvent the wheel with me

```
<body style="margin:0px;">

<div id="scroller" style="position:absolute;left:400px;width:800px;border:1px solid #000000;overflow:hidden;height:auto;">
<div id="scrollWrap" style="margin:0px;position:relative;width:400px;margin:auto;border:1px solid #000000;overflow:hidden;height:150px;">

<figure id="shark" style="float:left;margin:0px;padding:0px;width:150px;display:inline-block;">
<img  id="image" src="shark.jpeg" alt="The Shark" style="border:1px solid #000000;position:relative;left:0px;width:150px;height:150px;">
</figure>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 setInterval(function(){ do_move("shark"); }, 10);
</script>
</body>  

<script type="text/javascript">

    var frameDirection;

    function do_move(image) {

    var container = document.getElementById("scrollWrap");
    var bodyRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    var element = document.getElementById(image);
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    offset   = rect.left - bodyRect.left;

        fish = document.getElementById(image);
        horz = fish.style.left;
        fishSize = document.getElementById(image).offsetWidth;
        horz = parseInt(horz.substring(0,horz.length-2));

     var frameWidth = document.getElementById('scroller').offsetWidth;
     var wrapWidth = document.getElementById('scrollWrap').offsetWidth;
     var nbrImg =     document.getElementById("scrollWrap").getElementsByTagName("figure").length;
     if (horz==0) { 
        frameDirection='right';
     }
     else if (horz == (wrapWidth-fishSize)) {
        frameDirection='left';
     }
        if (horz<=wrapWidth && frameDirection == 'right') {
            horz += 1;
          fish.style.left = (horz)+'px';
        }   
        else if (horz<=wrapWidth && frameDirection == 'left') {
            horz -= 1;
          fish.style.left = (horz)+'px';
        }     
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to initially float your elements, then switch to absolute positioning, but keep everything in the same place, so you can animate them?

If so, this code may help you. It's not based on your html, just an example.

```
// get all the floating elements
var floaters = document.getElementsByClassName("floater"),
    index, floater, rect;
// go over them backwards
for (index=floaters.length-1; index>=0; index--) {
    floater = floaters[index];
    // get current position
    rect = floater.getBoundingClientRect();
    // convert it to style
    floater.style.left = rect.left + "px";
    floater.style.top = rect.top + "px";
    // switch to absolute positioning
    floater.style.position = "absolute";
    floater.style.float = "none";
}
```

I made a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/g5tc1u8h/2/), so you can test it.

Comment: Thank for your time. Well i guess you awnser my question by switching them to absolute poition to move them. The elements do need a position to be moved arround. So i will have to do the maths.

Comment: I thought you just wanted a floating-like initial position, without manually calculating it. If you can elaborate on what exactly are you trying to achieve, I might be able to help.